# Creating email accounts on Azure AppService

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

I have an app running on `Azure` `AppService`. I have also added a custom domain and everything seems to be working fine.

Right now, I need to know how is it possible to create email addresses using the domain name added to `AppService`. I am not able to find the MX record where I could register it with my domain provider.

Can someone tell me where I could locate the MX record from the Azure Portal.

If there's another way I could use the domain name to create emailIds please let me know.

Comment: You bought the domain from Azure or from a domain provider?

Comment: @CSharpRocks from a 3rd party domain provider.

Answer (score 0):

There's no email service in Azure.  You need to use a service like Office365 or Gmail and configure the MX record using the 3rd party domain provider admin page.

Comment: So is there a way I could locate where the MX record is in Azure ?

Comment: No since your domain is managed at the domain provider

Answer (score 0):

As per previous comments, there is no email service offered by Azure other than O365.

1. App Service is a PaaS Environment and being a sandboxed environment there are restrictions on port 25.
2. For Example – Port 25 is blocked on all outbound connections. Inbound connections are still valid.
3. I would recommend try to use port 587.
4. But for port 587, you need to make sure the email server accepts incoming connections at port 587.
5. The best recommendation is to use SendGrid to send emails, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email or TWILIO service.
6. If you do not want to use SendGrid, please try to configure a new outlook account to send emails on port 587.

In a nutshell, because of the sandboxed restrictions the outbound connectivity is blocked over port 25 and it may not be an option to go forward.

Please refer the article, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2017/11/15/enhanced-azure-security-for-sending-emails-november-2017-update/